# What and where are good (fast and easy) sources of Vials of Weak Blood

Tags: guild-wars-2

I'm going to get to level 20 soon and I'd like to craft as many pieces of equipment for that level, with power bonus for my character, as I can.

That requires a lot of Vials of Weak Blood

Can you suggest any places where mobs dropping it are in high quantities and preferably densely packed? :)

Comment: Even better would be ideal drop locations for all crafting ingredients :)

Comment: @SaintWacko I fear that that would be too broad for the site.

Comment: @FAE - Yeah, I guess there are quite a few of them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The river outside of the Township of Claypool is infested with brackish skale, and they drop vials of weak blood as their fine crafting material. The further you go downriver, the more dense they are.

Other foes that drop this item include minotaurs, harpies, bats, spiders, skelk, ridgeback skale, and bog skale - see [this relevant wiki page](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Vial_of_Weak_Blood).